# Firebase Realtime Database pricing calculation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say that my database looks like this :

```json
"users": {
  "userID1": {
    "profile": {
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Nhoj"
    },
    "some-extra-data": "lot of child nodes"
  }
}
```

I want to query `name` with `equalTo("John")`, how is the price calculated ?

Does it loop through all users records and charge it ? Or is it only 2 reads (`name` and `surname`) ?

I don't get how it actually query datas, I have the feeling that it reads for all user ids and look for `users/${userId}/profile/name == "John"`

So if there is 100k users, it will query 100k users to get the name and charge read of these 100k users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it loop through all users records?

Yes, it will check against all users. In order to know which child is "John", the query must evaluate all children within the node, and it will return as a result only the matching elements.

If your database gets bigger, then you should consider [adding a new database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding), simply by creating a new instance of the Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: the query must evaluate all children within the node => Do I pay for this ?

Comment: You pay for the amount of data you download. Don't confuse with Firestore, where you pay for the number of documents you read.